# List comprehension for nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am creating a simple card game and decided to implement list comprehension well try to. I don't really know how to approach this because I have only dealt with 1 for loop.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.cards = []  

    for suit in range(1, 5):  

        for value in range(2, 11):  
            self.cards.append(Card(value, suit))  

        for value in ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack']:  
            self.cards.append(Card(value, suit))
```

This is the nested for loop that I want to possibly put into a list comprehension, if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With nested loops you can write the comprehension as:

```
[expression for x in x_values for y in y_values]
```

Something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    values = list(range(2,11)) + ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack']
    self.cards = [Card(value, suit) for suit in range(1,5) for value in values]
```

I set up the `values` in a separate line so the comprehension wasn't too unwieldy. You could put it elsewhere as a constant if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The neatest way would leverage `itertools.chain`, so first:

```
from itertools import chain
```

Then simply:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.cards = [
        Card(value, suit)
        for suit in range(1, 5)
        for value in chain(range(2, 11), ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack'])
    ]
```

Or even without `itertools`:

```
num_vals = range(2, 11)
face_vals = ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack']
self.cards = [
    Card(value, suit))
    for suit in range(1, 5)
    for values in (num_vals, face_vals)
    for value in values
]
```